# Sharing code between Objective-C classes, like Traits in PHP

Tags: objective-c, class

How can I share code between classes in Objective-C, the way Traits in PHP work?

I thought of using categories, but I wondered if there is something more suitable when it wouldn't be sensible to use inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to share code between classes and each one has its own importance, depending upon the situation:

1. You can use `inheritance`.
2. You can declare Global Methods.
3. You can put the sharable code in `AppDelegate`.
4. You can use Singleton Class and put the common code in that class. (Not preferred for sharing code but we can still do it.)

All methods have their own pros/cons. You need to study their applications and use. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Depends. You should ask yourself why do you want to have the same behaviour in various classes. You can use: Inheritance or design patterns (e.g. Composite pattern).

See:
[Does Objective-C support traits/mixins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601126/does-objective-c-support-traits-mixins)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best practice, or what you mean by "sharing code" but I usually have a static class which can hold global values.

The class is static and you can access it from anywhere like this:

```
[dataModel getMyValue];
[dataModel setMyValue];
```

It only becomes an issues if you try to write to it from multiple threads, but other than that its a good way to store shared data in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing code in Objective-C can be done only via subclassing or doing composition.

There is no equivalent of PHP's traits here. Categories work in a little bit different way. They're are assigned to a certain class, so you can't use code from category in any class. Unless you create NSObject category, which is good idea only in rare cases. You can treat category as a class extension.

It's possible 'share' interfaces having many different protocols. But it's not exactly what you need, I guess.